# Notion API returns empty filled relation property

Tags: request, webhooks, notion-api

I'm trying to use the API of notion to acquire a property of type relation, but, although the UI of notion has pages linked to this property, when using the api to acquire it, it does not return any linked pages, as if the property were empty

the application has permission to read in both databases, the relationship is 2 way connected, I've tried using
`get https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/page id` 
and
`get https://api.notion.com/v1/pages/page id/properties/prop id` 
and both return the empty property, and in the UI there are connected pages

the property appears like this

```json
'Personagens': {'id': 'pPhq', 'type': 'relation', 'relation': [], 'has_more': False}
```

the list in the 'relation' key should have 2 pages, but it's completely empty, which doesn't make sense, because as I said, the property is connected with another property in the related database and both are connected to the application that has the authorization to read, what's wrong? how can I solve?

Comment: Make sure you have setup the integration connection to the related databases.